# O365 TenantToTenantMigration- Azure AD Users

Tags: migration, office365, azure-active-directory

How can i migrate the Azure AD users from old O365 tenant to the new O365 tenant in a tenant to tenant migration situation. Also will it involve any downtime on the old tenant.

How can i migrate the external users to the new tenant and retain the permissions

Please help..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to migrate all users from one tenant to another tenant?

Comment: See if  this article is helpful: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-from-one-office-365-tenant-to-another-65af7d77-3e79-44d4-9173-04fd991358b7